# ScriptParameters/Keys, can this hold the name of the Excel sheet?

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

Hello Power Automate pros,

I'm really new to the tool and building my first flow which automates on Excel files using OfficeScript code. I'm trying to write OfficeScripts code that is agnostic to the Sheet names or tables names.

I'm want to know; on a "Run Script" step for a Manually triggered flow, can the field ScriptParameters/Keys hold the name of sheet or the table the User wants to process/automate on?
If yes, can this field also hold a column header name?

If not where else can the user have the an Opportunity to input names of sheets that are used then referred to in the code?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters and yes, you can add multiple of them and have the user be prompted to enter values for those parameters on execution from PowerAutomate. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Hello @Skin Thanks for the info. I found how to prompt the user to input a parameter within Excel using an Office Script directly on the Workbook but don't know how have a prompt in PowerAutomate so the user can input those vales.

What is that called in PowerAutomate? I'd like to find the documentation on how do achive that.

Comment: Manually trigger a flow with a button. The button can have prompts attached to it. Otherwise adaptive cards are your friends.